# jQuery AutoComplete data from route and using custom data and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Here is the code I'm attempting to use (parts pulled from remote json, parts removed from the custom data display):

```
$(function () {
    $("#Field1Text").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Main/Users/GetItems",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    group: "Default",
                    query: request.term
                }
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Field1Text").val(ui.item.Description);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Field1Text").val(ui.item.Description);

            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><strong>" + item.Description + "</strong><br>" + item.Section + " - " + item.Type + " - " + item.Name + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

The data pulls back fine, but the render item function never fires. I've scrapped the render item version and used success: inside of source and it looked like this:

```
 success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (ul, item) {
                        return $("<li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append("<a><strong>" + item.Description + "</strong><br>" + item.Section + " - " + item.Type + " - " + item.Name + "</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    }));
                }
```

I used firebug and I was able to hit a breakpoint at the response section: if I looked at the data in data, it looked like:

`[ Object { ...data... }, Object { ...data... }]`

If I set a breakpoint at the `.data` line of the success section, I see that ul is one of the objects `( looks like " Object { ... data ... }")`

the item element is 0 at this point, and when I attempt to render the `<a>` tags, it comes out as Undefined on all of the properties (understandable, looks to be treating the item object as an `int`).

How do I get that component to handle properly?

edit: sorry, I wanted to add a jsFiddle per the suggestion in the comments but had family stuff going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/EYj8v/2/

I commented the code that is similar to what we use at work. Unfortunately, the web app is an internal one with a database that isn't connected to the outside world so I can't use live data. The testResults object is what I saw in the success: section's data element.

I was actually able to get the success section to fire, but I don't believe I'm using jQuery UI/Autocomplete correctly (at least my assumptions) as I was able to look at ul.Properties and see real data. Appending the  items worked with bogus data, but when I attempted to copy and paste the success block into the render item, all of the data was undefined. Nor could I find a one-to-one mapping at that stage (ul was the element on the page, item was just [li]).

Comment: suggest creating a demo in jsfiddle.net, replace the AJAX source with sample data stored in variable

Comment: What is the structure of the data coming back?

Comment: charlie, good call. I added a jsFiddle. I can't seem to get it to render any type of drop down, so I'm going to try and play with it a bit to hopefully get it working. Andrew, the data as it was showing in Firebug is included as testResults.

Comment: Your JavaScript object literal is wrong. The word "Object" shouldn't be before each object. I would check to see how your server-side code is serializing the objects you're sending down. Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/V753C/

Comment: I'm using JSON.NET with the SerializeObject(list) method. I'm not sure if it truly outputs Object in the code, but that was what firebug was showing.

Comment: I saw in the demo version I included a semicolon that should've been commented out (it was in place for the .data commenting out and attempting to only use the success: item to render it).

Is there a chance you can look at the success section and tell me where to look in the API that outlines where I'm going wrong with it? I looked through the jQuery UI documentation and didn't see anything relating to success. Stepping through the script in firebug, I was able to get into the append section and the items had data, but when it rendered, it was ~5px rows in the dropdown with no data rendered.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EYj8v/3/ note that it deviates from the remote autocomplete example on the jQuery UI site in that the items I'm trying to pull data from is the ul, which is odd because my expectation is that it should have been item (due to mapping)? I think to really understand this, I'm going to have to learn javascript as it is pretty different to what I'm used to in C# (not a bad thing, just different). Also, the data won't map out, so it will require some pretending (internal database and website at work, unfortunately not exposed externally). It does come out like testResults though.

Comment: I got it. The primary issue is that in success, it wasn't rendering item off that. I needed to do function(data) {response(data); } and it is functioning properly now.